# I want to change the data type of a list, how can i do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_score = 0
counter = 0
scores = []
while user_score != "done":
    print("type 'done' if you're done inputting")
    user_score = input("write ur score here:").lower()
    scores.append(user_score)
    counter += 1

counter -= 1
scores.pop()
output = 0

print(type(scores[0]))
result = sum(scores)
print(result)
```

so i want to create a program where i ll input some numbers and get the average. so the problem is i can t sum up the elements in the "score" variable because they are in string type.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `result = sum(scores)` with `result = sum(map(float, scores))`.

This will apply `float()` to every element of `scores`, converting them into floats before adding them up.

This is probably less [*pythonic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) than list comprehension. So the other answer might provide better readability. It will use up less memory though. Not that this will matter in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
scores = [int(x) for x in scores]
```

at the end of your loop and after the pop to turn the array into ints

Answer (score 0):

Like [Nikita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74765668/14915698) says, you can create a new collection of items which have been type-casted using the `map` function. I recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to learn more about how it works.

As an alternative, you can use a list comprehension to accomplish the same thing:

```py
scores = [float(score) for score in scores]
result = sum(scores)
```

It's best practice to use whichever you find more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add only **integers** to **scores** so you can use [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check if a **str** value is **numberic** or **str** and **append** only if it is **numberic**.

If you do so, then you **do not need** to **pop** the last element from the list.

Also do not forget **type-cast** the **str** to **int**

```
user_score = 0
counter = 0
scores = []

while user_score != "done":
    print("type 'done' if you're done inputting")
    user_score = input("write ur score here:").lower()
    if user_score.isnumeric():
      scores.append(int(user_score))
      
    counter += 1

result = sum(scores)
print(result)
```

Comment: Checking the user's input type is probably beyond the scope of OP's requirements right now, but if you want to include it to be helpful, please include some ways to handle it with an `else` clause. Using `continue` is a common practice in this case.